how do I update a variable with the contents of a textbox from inside a function?
I'm new to Python but not new to writing code. I'm attempting to write an adventure game as a way to stretch an assignment for a course. I can't use any extensions or libraries that don't come packaged with Python so I'm using Tkinter as my GUI.
I'm trying to build the setup portion of the game where the player defines their name. I want them to type a name into a text box and click a Submit button causing the PlayerName global variable to update with the contents of the text box.
def PreGame_1():
    display_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
    display_frame.pack()
    title_label = ttk.Label(display_frame, text="Welcome brave adventurer, what is your name?")
    title_label.pack()
    NameField = ttk.Entry(display_frame)
    NameButton = ttk.Button(display_frame, text="Submit")
    NameField.pack()
    NameButton.pack()
    ContinueButton = ttk.Button(display_frame, text="Continue", command=PreGame_2)
    ContinueButton.pack()

I have a second function ready to go:
def CreatePlayerName():
    playername = NameField.get()

My problem is where do I put it? If I put it inside PreGame_1 then I get an error complaining that CreatePlayerName is a variable without a defined value even though its a Function, not a variable.
If I define it outside as a separate Function then NameField is out of scope because it's defined inside PreGame_1
How do I solve this?

which part of your question is about the Raspberry Pi?
